# SimpleSAML and Symantec O3

Tags: php, saml, saml-2.0, symantec, simplesamlphp

I'm trying to configure SimpleSAML to allow authentication via an external login portal powered by Symantec O3.

I've set up SimpleSAML as a SP by editing config/authsources.php and converting the respectful meta data. I've provided my meta data to the administrators of the external login portal.

When I visit the test authentication page, I am correctly redirected to the login portal however after logging in I get redirected back to SimpleSAML but instead of seeing my identify information I receive the following error:

```
May 19 12:07:04 m63701 simplesamlphp[14270]: 3 [827f6e2b0c] SimpleSAML_Error_BadRequest: BADREQUEST('%REASON%' => 'Missing TARGET parameter.')
May 19 12:07:04 m63701 simplesamlphp[14270]: 3 [827f6e2b0c] Backtrace:
May 19 12:07:04 m63701 simplesamlphp[14270]: 3 [827f6e2b0c] 1 /home/web/simplesaml/modules/saml/www/sp/saml1-acs.php:8 (require)
May 19 12:07:04 m63701 simplesamlphp[14270]: 3 [827f6e2b0c] 0 /home/web/simplesaml/www/module.php:135 (N/A)
May 19 12:07:04 m63701 simplesamlphp[14270]: 3 [827f6e2b0c] Error report with id c359a4f1 generated.
```

It appears not to know where to redirect to after authentication.

This doesn't look like an issue with the test functionality as although it appears to authenticate I get the same error message when implementing the authentication in a plain php file. Is there any particular configuration I should check and set?

Answer (score 1):

This issue was caused by a configuration issue at the IDP's side.

Symantec O3 was configured to use a SAML2 connector however the ACS URL was configured to point to the SAML1 endpoint.

Updating the ACS URL to the SAML2 endpoint which is contained in the SimpleSAMLPHP metadata